# Programmatically enabling auto update on google play store for an application

Tags: android, google-play

We are facing one issue, when we are publishing application via OEM, it's not asking for auto-update to the user. On analysis, we found that app is of news category which is causing it. Is it possible to enable auto-update this application for programmatically?

How play store update only partial application instead of downloading complete application and then updating, it just update the delta dex file.

Answer (score 1):

> it's not asking for auto-update to the user

It's user action. You cannot enforce or silently turn it on on non-rooted devices.

Comment: We are ok to display some dialog to the user and ask for it, problem is auto-update is ON on play store but still it's not asking for system application because it's of News category. User can still go to the play store and update it.

Comment: so when you say it's not possible for non-rooted devices but what about OEM app. Is there any provision we can set so that if we are delivering our app as OEM then it switch auto-update as ON

Comment: I'd say that's odd really. system app or not, news or not should not matter, if there's update available then it should be served, esp. you can do this manually. Please note that you can have auto update in store enabled but still disable per particular app. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: It seems to be so. Auto update is ON on play store but only our app is not getting updated and its happening only on devices where app has been delivered as OEM app.

Comment: I meant that on rooted devices you are almighty, incl. powers to change anything in the system like system files, db etc. So this information must be stored somewhere - and if so, having powers you can play with that storage. I am not aware of any API or other cleaner way here, but I may simply lack of knowledge on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play recently announced that they will be launching Immediate In-App Update. A new API that allows you to prompt users to update without ever leaving your app. You can have a look at this [tweet](https://twitter.com/GooglePlayDev/status/1052850625984307200) for the announcement. This might solve your issue as it will ask the user to auto-update from within your app.